# Insert child element in the right order when working with OpenXML

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, openxml-sdk, system.xml

I'm modifying `.docx` documents with `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` library. I know [element ordering is important](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12221477/809357), otherwise the document will not pass schema validation and might result a document that can't be opened in Word.

Now I need to add a `DocumentProtection` element to `DocumentSettingsPart`. And I need to insert this child element in the right place inside of a parent.

The schema looks like this:

[image: OpenXML Schema]

There are quite a lot of possible ordering of child elements. At the moment I'm adding this element like this:

```
var documentProtection = new DocumentProtection()
{
    // do the configuration
};

DocumentSettingsPart settings = doc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart;
var rootElement = settings.RootElement;
var prevElement = 
                rootElement.GetFirstChild<DoNotTrackFormatting>() ??
                rootElement.GetFirstChild<DoNotTrackMoves>() ??
                rootElement.GetFirstChild<TrackRevisions>() ??
                rootElement.GetFirstChild<RevisionView>() ??
                rootElement.GetFirstChild<DocumentType>() ??
                rootElement.GetFirstChild<StylePaneSortMethods>() ??
                // SNIP
                rootElement.GetFirstChild<Zoom>() ??
                rootElement.GetFirstChild<View>() ??
                (OpenXmlLeafElement)rootElement.GetFirstChild<WriteProtection>();
rootElement.InsertAfter(documentProtection, prevElement);
```

I.e. I'm trying to find if any possible element that should go before mine already exists in the document. And then insert `DocumentProtection` after that element. And given amount of elements this list gets pretty boring.

**Is there a better way to add `DocumentProtection` so it is schema compliant and does not involve enumeration of all possible elements?**

Comment: Interesting question... It might be a good idea to add appropriate XML tag(s) to this question as an optimal answer might already be a "known" in the XML world. The InnerXml property of rootElement should give you the XML as a string which can analyzed differently than OOXML object model. Using a "Find" of some kind, for example. But there might be a special trick for this the XML pros know?

Comment: @CindyMeister thanks for suggestion - added `xml` and `xsd` tags. I was really hoping not to go down to XML/XSD analysis if it can be helped.

Comment: It's possible that System.XML folks might also know a general way for handling something like this in an "object model" approach. You could remove the openxml tag and add that one, as well....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a nice way to achieve what you want. You'll have to tinker with the collection and you're responsible for keeping the order correct.

Using ILSpy on the [Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.settings.aspx) class you'll find that the implementors used a helper method `SetElement<T>` on the base class that takes a position and an instance to insert.

Unfortunately that helper method is marked `internal` so we can't leverage it if you try to subclass `Settings`. Instead I re-implemented the needed functionality so you'll have a subclass of `Settings` that does offer a property for `DocumentProtection` but uses the re-implemented solution to find the correct location to insert the node:

#### SettingsExt

```
public class SettingsExt: Settings
{
    // contruct based on XML
    public SettingsExt(string outerXml)
        :base(outerXml)
    {
        // empty
    }

    public DocumentProtection DocumentProtection
    {
        // get is easy
        get
        {
            return this.GetFirstChild<DocumentProtection>();
        }
        // reimplemented SetElement based on 
        // reversed engineered Settings class
        set
        {

            // eleTagNames is a static string[] declared later
            // it holds all the names of the elements in the right order
            int sequenceNumber = eleTagNames
                .Select((s, i) => new { s= s, idx = i })
                    .Where(s => s.s == "documentProtection")
                    .Select((s) => s.idx)
                    .First(); 
            OpenXmlElement openXmlElement = this.FirstChild;

            OpenXmlElement refChild = null;
            while (openXmlElement != null)
            {
                // a bit naive
                int currentSequence = eleTagNames
                    .Select((s, i) => new { s = s, idx = i })
                    .Where(s => s.s == openXmlElement.LocalName)
                    .Select((s) => s.idx)
                    .First(); ; 
                if (currentSequence == sequenceNumber)
                {
                    if (openXmlElement is DocumentProtection)
                    {
                        refChild = openXmlElement.PreviousSibling();
                        this.RemoveChild<OpenXmlElement>(openXmlElement);
                        break;
                    }
                    refChild = openXmlElement;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (currentSequence > sequenceNumber)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    refChild = openXmlElement;
                }
                openXmlElement = openXmlElement.NextSibling();
            }
            if (value != null)
            {
                this.InsertAfter(value, refChild);
            }
        }
    }
    
    // order of elements in the sequence!
    static readonly string[] eleTagNames = new string[]
    {
        "writeProtection",
        "view",
        "zoom",
        "removePersonalInformation",
        "removeDateAndTime",
        "doNotDisplayPageBoundaries",
        "displayBackgroundShape",
        "printPostScriptOverText",
        "printFractionalCharacterWidth",
        "printFormsData",
        "embedTrueTypeFonts",
        "embedSystemFonts",
        "saveSubsetFonts",
        "saveFormsData",
        "mirrorMargins",
        "alignBordersAndEdges",
        "bordersDoNotSurroundHeader",
        "bordersDoNotSurroundFooter",
        "gutterAtTop",
        "hideSpellingErrors",
        "hideGrammaticalErrors",
        "activeWritingStyle",
        "proofState",
        "formsDesign",
        "attachedTemplate",
        "linkStyles",
        "stylePaneFormatFilter",
        "stylePaneSortMethod",
        "documentType",
        "mailMerge",
        "revisionView",
        "trackRevisions",
        "doNotTrackMoves",
        "doNotTrackFormatting",
        "documentProtection",
        "autoFormatOverride",
        "styleLockTheme",
        "styleLockQFSet",
        "defaultTabStop",
        "autoHyphenation",
        "consecutiveHyphenLimit",
        "hyphenationZone",
        "doNotHyphenateCaps",
        "showEnvelope",
        "summaryLength",
        "clickAndTypeStyle",
        "defaultTableStyle",
        "evenAndOddHeaders",
        "bookFoldRevPrinting",
        "bookFoldPrinting",
        "bookFoldPrintingSheets",
        "drawingGridHorizontalSpacing",
        "drawingGridVerticalSpacing",
        "displayHorizontalDrawingGridEvery",
        "displayVerticalDrawingGridEvery",
        "doNotUseMarginsForDrawingGridOrigin",
        "drawingGridHorizontalOrigin",
        "drawingGridVerticalOrigin",
        "doNotShadeFormData",
        "noPunctuationKerning",
        "characterSpacingControl",
        "printTwoOnOne",
        "strictFirstAndLastChars",
        "noLineBreaksAfter",
        "noLineBreaksBefore",
        "savePreviewPicture",
        "doNotValidateAgainstSchema",
        "saveInvalidXml",
        "ignoreMixedContent",
        "alwaysShowPlaceholderText",
        "doNotDemarcateInvalidXml",
        "saveXmlDataOnly",
        "useXSLTWhenSaving",
        "saveThroughXslt",
        "showXMLTags",
        "alwaysMergeEmptyNamespace",
        "updateFields",
        "hdrShapeDefaults",
        "footnotePr",
        "endnotePr",
        "compat",
        "docVars",
        "rsids",
        "mathPr",
        "uiCompat97To2003",
        "attachedSchema",
        "themeFontLang",
        "clrSchemeMapping",
        "doNotIncludeSubdocsInStats",
        "doNotAutoCompressPictures",
        "forceUpgrade",
        "captions",
        "readModeInkLockDown",
        "smartTagType",
        "schemaLibrary",
        "shapeDefaults",
        "doNotEmbedSmartTags",
        "decimalSymbol",
        "listSeparator",
        "docId",
        "discardImageEditingData",
        "defaultImageDpi",
        "conflictMode"};

}
```

A typical usage scenario with this class is as follows:

```
using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"c:\tmp\test.docx", true))
{

    var documentProtection = new DocumentProtection()
    {
        Formatting = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OnOffValue.FromBoolean(true)
    };

    DocumentSettingsPart settings = doc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart;

    // instantiate our ExtendedSettings class based on the
    // original Settings
    var extset = new SettingsExt(settings.Settings.OuterXml);

    // new or existing?
    if (extset.DocumentProtection == null)
    {
        extset.DocumentProtection = documentProtection;
    }
    else
    {
        // replace existing values
    }

    // this is key to make sure our own DOMTree is saved!
    // don't forget this
    settings.Settings = extset;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is pretty intense! Not an easy solution by a margin. Thanks for sharing - pretty valuable peace of code.

Comment: Adding my thanks, as well: this is a super reference :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is an `AddChild()` method that adds the child in the correct order according to the schema.

It's possible that this method was added in the 3.0 version of the Office OpenXML SDK (Microsoft nuget package).

I can't find any information about this when Googleing, not even the [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com) website has anything about it.

But here is an image of the IntelliSense definition. I have verified in my code that this works as advertised :)

[image]

A **warning** though. It appears if you call `AddChild()` multiple times with the same type of child, it will overwrite the existing child :/ (bug?)
Workaround is to use this type of code logic:

```
var existingElements = wsp.Worksheet.Elements<ConditionalFormatting>();
var count = existingElements.Count();

ConditionalFormatting cf = new ConditionalFormatting();
...

if (count == 0)
{
    wsp.Worksheet.AddChild(cf);
}
else wsp.Worksheet.InsertAfter(cf, existingElements.Last());
```